# Postback url untriggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, autopostback

I am actually on a projext using ASP.NET Webforms, and I encountered the following problem :

I have a page with a button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" Text="Interrupt" ValidationGroup="later"
            OnClick="btnSaveLater_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm(Are you sure?')"
            CssClass="saveLaterButton" meta:resourcekey="btnStopResource1"/>
```

and the event code :

```
public void btnSaveLater_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session[Constante.cSessionToPage] = Constante.cPageStudyboard;
    this.SaveData(FID_COMMON_LIB.Enum.eStatutItw.Termine);
    btnStop.PostBackUrl = (String.Format("{0{PageLancementITW.aspx", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NominativeWebSite"].ToString()));
}
```

On this page, I have a user control, with following code :

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel_QV4" runat="server" CssClass="row-fluid questionGroup">
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcb_ID_GERME" runat="server" OnDataBound="rcb_ID_GERME_DataBound" DataSourceID="DS_GERME" DataValueField="ID_GERME" DataTextField="GERME_NOM" MarkFirstMatch="true" CssClass="txtBox10char" AllowCustomText="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TextBoxQV4_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ExpandDirection="Down"></telerik:RadComboBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

with the event code retrieving some data from database

The problem is that the autopostback is only triggered when a value is choosen in the combo box.
I followed the code step-by-step, and it is exactly the same for both cases. What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

If your combobox is in the `later` validation group, and the validation fails for the combobox, it won't run the Click event for your button. Check to make sure you don't have any validation errors.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some more information on validation groups.

Comment: I've just tried deleting this tag - nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using ValidationGroups on this page? Show more code so we can see what exactly is going on in the page.